# Unhandled exception in Grails 3

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

I have upgraded my application from Grails 2 to 3 and have a problem with unhandled exceptions that I didn't get before.

In UrlMappings I have listed some urls and where to redirect, but if I would misspell a name I get an unhandled exception.

```
"/page" (controller: 'page', action: 'getPage')
"/" ( view: 'index' )   
"500" (view:'/error')
```

So if I would go to myHomePage/ I would redirect to index, but if I would go to myHomePage/pages I would get "OOPS! an unhandled exception occurred". In Grails 2 I would get a not found (404).

Anyone who have a suggesstion or know how to fix this?

Comment: Can you show us any logs?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in application.yml

```
grails:
    web:
        servlet:
            path: /*
```

Based on the answer to this question: [grails 3 war in JBoss EAP 6.2.0 does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33143965/grails-3-war-in-jboss-eap-6-2-0-does-not-work)