# grails 3 war in JBoss EAP 6.2.0 does not work

Tags: jboss, grails-3.0

When I try to run a very simple grails 3 (3.0.7) application as war (with embedded tomcat removed) in JBoss EAP 6.2.0.GA (AS 7.3.0.Final-redhat-14) all requests end up in a HTTP 404.
The same war works in Tomcat.

Searching the web I found the following related to Spring Boot:

[springBoot application on Jboss EAP, servlet context not lodaed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27576629/springboot-application-on-jboss-eap-servlet-context-not-lodaed)

Unfortunately configuring the property *server.servlet-path* in *application.yml* (in yml format) did not work.

Answer (score 3):

Looking into the grails 3 source:

https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-controllers/src/main/groovy/org/grails/plugins/web/controllers/ControllersGrailsPlugin.groovy#L79

I found the solution.
In *application.yml* add the following configuration:

```
grails:
    web:
        servlet:
            path: /*
```

starting with *web:* into the existing *grails:* section.
Then all requests are working as again as expected.