# HTTP 404 after deploying WAR file in Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0) openshif

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, jboss, openshift

I Developed my WAR file with netbeans and Tomcat 7 on my local machine and I used this tutorial to help deploy it on openshift Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0) [link](https://developers.openshift.com/servers/tomcat/deployment-options.html) but I keep getting a `HTTP 404 error` from little research it seems to a be a configuration issue or a native library issue, gotten from this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33895757/deploying-war-to-openshift-404-error-not-found/34178165)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error was caused twice by different root causes:

1. Catalina cache doesn't return requested Java Server Page
2. Low disk space on the partition where the cache directory resides

Description:

The keepgenerated attribute should be set in web.xml

In default this attribute is not set and server keeps generated server pages in the cache folder (mine is named work under tomcat)
We had to manually delete the content of that cache directory.

Solution for cause 1:

Add the ‘keepgenerated’ attribute into web.xml with 'false' value as following

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>fork</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>keepgenerated</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>   
</servlet>
```

Solution for cause 2:

- Free some disk space
- Reload tomcat configuration